# Difference between cmd and browser connect with proxy

Tags: node.js, maven, cmd, proxy

I'm working with network using company's proxy. With some `https links`, I can connect it using browsers, but can not using with `cmd command`. Example:
When I working with android-studio with link: `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ (~ mavenCentral())` it not working, I have to change it to `maven { url:http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ }`. But, with browsers I can connected to the `https` link. The same errors when I working with any `npm install (cordova, ionic...)` commands.

So, my question is "What are the differences between cmd and browser connect with proxy?".

Comment: Check your settings.xml where you define the proxy configuration

Comment: I came here after done it. I used this tutorial [link](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-enable-proxy-setting-in-maven/). Anyway, can you answer my main question?

Comment: Can you show an output by `mvn clean package`...